# multithreaded program causes segmentation fault, uses std::list::push_back

Tags: c++, multithreading

**Class definition**

```
class TaskWorker
{
    ...
    private:
            std::list<client_det*> clientList;
    ...

    public:
            void waitForClientResponse();
};
```

**Function to run class member function as thread**

```
void* waitForResponse(void* w)
{
    TaskWorker* worker = static_cast<TaskWorker*>(w);
    worker->waitForClientResponse();
}
```

**Thread function implementation**

```
void TaskWorker::waitForClientResponse()
{
    client_det* obj = new client_det();
    ...
    clientList.push_back(obj); //valgrind says access violation
    ...
}
```

Is there anything wrong in this implementation?
Is there any limitation in thread class member function accessing private member list?

**Thread invocation**

```
int TaskWorker::assign_and_wait(std::list<MulticastGroupInfo*> groupList)
{
     ...
     ...               
     pthread_t tid;
     pthread_create(&tid, NULL, waitForResponse, this);
}
```

**Update**

I compiled my code without debug symbols and the crash is gone. This is my latest observation.
Anyone can enlighten me what is going on here?

Comment: Are you sure that `w` is not `NULL`?

Comment: @HAL I have added the code which invokes the thread function. I am passing `this` from another member function. Is that right?

Comment: How many threads are trying to modify `clientList` at the same time?

Comment: This thread pushes into the list and another thread pops  out. But unless the push happens, other thread wont pop.

Comment: Are you doing any unsafe C style string copy etc. on a class member in `TaskWorker::assign_and_wait()` or `TaskWorker::waitForClientResponse()`?

Comment: @HAL I am doing lot of such things.

Comment: @cppcoder Please use std:string for any string handling. If you really can't then at least use the comparatively safer C functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things that may cause a segmentation fault in your code:

- The instance of `TaskWorker` could be `NULL` as there is no null check in `void* waitForResponse(void* w)`. This can cause an access violation in `void TaskWorker::waitForClientResponse()` at the very first access to a member variable.
- Please avoid any unsafe C style string operations. For example, If you're not careful enough with `strcpy`, it will overflow your buffer and overwrite some unrelated memory.
- If multiple threads share `clientList`(or any other shared resource), please make sure that you have an appropriate mutual exclusion mechanism in place.

Comment: If `w` was NULL `worker->waitForClientResponse()` itself would have failed

Comment: @cppcoder: If w was NULL then `worker->waitForClientResponse()` invokes undefined behavior. It is common for non-virtual member function calls on a null pointer to appear to succeed until you try to access a member variable of the non-existent object. (For example: https://ideone.com/4jr2ur)